OverflowError When Setting Up gym_super_mario_bros Environment in Python on JupyterLab
I’ve been following a tutorial on YouTube (https://youtu.be/2eeYqJ0uBKE?si=Vx6gybqKh3ApSfXV) to build a Super Mario AI model using Python. However, when setting up the gym_super_mario_bros environment, I encounter an OverflowError. Here’s the code I’m using:
# Import the game
import gym_super_mario_bros
# Import the Joypad wrapper
from nes_py.wrappers import JoypadSpace
# Import the SIMPLIFIED controls
from gym_super_mario_bros.actions import SIMPLE_MOVEMENT

# Setup game
env = gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-v0')
env = JoypadSpace(env, SIMPLE_MOVEMENT)

and this is the error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 2
      1 # Setup game
----> 2 env = gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-v0')
      3 env = JoypadSpace(env, SIMPLE_MOVEMENT)

File /Volumes/-/mario ai/mario/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py:592, in make(id, max_episode_steps, autoreset, disable_env_checker, **kwargs)
    588 else:
    589     # Assume it's a string
    590     env_creator = load(spec_.entry_point)
--> 592 env = env_creator(**_kwargs)
    594 # Copies the environment creation specification and kwargs to add to the environment specification details
    595 spec_ = copy.deepcopy(spec_)

File /Volumes/-/mario ai/mario/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym_super_mario_bros/smb_env.py:52, in SuperMarioBrosEnv.__init__(self, rom_mode, lost_levels, target)
     50 rom = rom_path(lost_levels, rom_mode)
     51 # initialize the super object with the ROM path
---> 52 super(SuperMarioBrosEnv, self).__init__(rom)
     53 # set the target world, stage, and area variables
     54 target = decode_target(target, lost_levels)

File /Volumes/-/mario ai/mario/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nes_py/nes_env.py:126, in NESEnv.__init__(self, rom_path)
    124     raise ValueError('ROM has trainer. trainer is not supported.')
    125 # try to read the PRG ROM and raise a value error if it fails
--> 126 _ = rom.prg_rom
    127 # try to read the CHR ROM and raise a value error if it fails
    128 _ = rom.chr_rom

File /Volumes/-/mario ai/mario/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nes_py/_rom.py:204, in ROM.prg_rom(self)
    202 """Return the PRG ROM of the ROM file."""
    203 try:
--> 204     return self.raw_data[self.prg_rom_start:self.prg_rom_stop]
    205 except IndexError:
    206     raise ValueError('failed to read PRG-ROM on ROM.')

File /Volumes/-/mario ai/mario/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nes_py/_rom.py:198, in ROM.prg_rom_stop(self)
    195 @property
    196 def prg_rom_stop(self):
    197     """The exclusive stopping index of the PRG ROM."""
--> 198     return self.prg_rom_start + self.prg_rom_size * 2**10

OverflowError: Python integer 1024 out of bounds for uint8

This error occurs when I try to create the environment with gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-v0'). I’m using Python 3.10 and the latest version of gym_super_mario_bros, all running on JupyterLab on my Mac. Does anyone have an idea how I might fix this error or what might be causing it?

I was following a different tutorial here - https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/mario_rl_tutorial.html, and got the same error message.
Have you tried older python versions?  Python 3.8.7 worked for me.
Also had to use an older version of Torch and numpy.  here's my whole requirements file:
certifi==2024.7.4
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
cloudpickle==3.0.0
colorama==0.4.6
filelock==3.15.4
fsspec==2024.6.1
gym==0.26.2
gym-notices==0.0.8
gym-super-mario-bros==7.4.0
idna==3.7
importlib_metadata==8.2.0
Jinja2==3.1.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
mpmath==1.3.0
nes_py==8.2.1
networkx==3.1
numpy==1.24.4
packaging==24.1
pillow==10.4.0
pyglet==1.5.21
requests==2.32.3
sympy==1.13.1
tensordict==0.3.0
torch==2.2.0
torchaudio==2.2.0
torchrl==0.3.0
torchvision==0.17.0
tqdm==4.66.5
typing_extensions==4.12.2
urllib3==2.2.2
zipp==3.19.2


I have the same issue but the main issue of numpy version 2.0.0. or 2.0.0>
I would like you to advice downgrade with the following command:
pip install 'numpy<2.0.0'

If you have numpy==2.0.0. or numpy>2.0.0
>>> numpy.uint8(255) + 256 * numpy.uint8(255)
OverflowError: Python integer 256 out of bounds for uint8

If you have numpy<2.0.0:
>>> numpy.uint8(255) + 256 * numpy.uint8(255)
65535
>>> type(_)
<class 'numpy.int64'>

